# Traveling from LAX to Cape Town with Turkish Airlines

Tags: transit, layovers, isl, turkish-airlines

I am traveling business class with Turkish Airlines from LAX to Cape Town with a 5-hour layover at Ataturk. Can I proceed to the lounge without going through customs?

Comment: Which lounge were you hoping to reach?

Comment: Yes, just make sure you have your boarding pass for your connecting flight first, before you go upstairs.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you may use the Turkish Airlines departure lounge in the transit zone. It is specifically built for transit passengers and doesn't require you to enter Turkey.